# Finding correlation between two variables

Tags: r, correlation

How do I know that the following variables are related (in general, any two variables)?

Below, there is an obvious relation between x and y however, the 'cor' function is giving me  '0'. Is there any function in R that can detect both linear and non-linear relation?

```
> x <- c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)
> y <- c(4,   1, 0, 1, 4)
> 
> cor(x,y)
[1] 0
>
```

Edit:
I am thinking to go for MIC/MINE algorithm despite many criticisms of this algorithm by top statisticians.

Comment: The general strategy involves plotting the data. In order to test for a relationship you need to define it. Otherwise we enter the domain of philosophy and could discuss wether everything is related.

Comment: I have thousands of such relation and this is not possible to plot and analyze each manually. What will be your take in this case?

Comment: My take would be that such a datamining exercise is dubious at best.

Comment: I voted to close this as I felt it to be more of a stats/methods question than specifically about programming.

Comment: It's a tricky decision about whether to keep this question open.  On one hand, it's impossible to answer "how do you detect arbitrary relationships between two variables".  On the other hand, that's still quite an interesting question.

Comment: As the comments to topchef's answer suggest,  there really isn't a correlation between `x` and `y` . There is a correlation between `y` and some particular functions `f(x)` .   If you have "thousands" of independent sample sets, and you expect each one to have a **different**  nonlinear correlation, you're doomed.

Comment: This is a standard homework question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [MINE](http://www.exploredata.net/) (1). They also provide a wrapper for R.

(1) Reshef, D.N, Y.A Reshef, H.K Finucane, S.R Grossman, G. McVean, P.J Turnbaugh, E.S Lander, M. Mitzenmacher, and P.C Sabeti. “Detecting Novel Associations in Large Data Sets.” Science 334, no. 6062 (2011): 1518–1524.

Comment: This is what I am thinking to go for. On other note, its a shame that we could not found any general algorithm to answer this very basic question

Comment: the problem is to find a `general` algorithm for a `very general` question. Its like asking what combinations of numbers add up to 5 (not exactly :), but you get the idea).

Comment: To echo @Arun: It's not a trivial exercise to detect non-linear relationships.